# What are the cases when should.deep.equal fails but comparison using JSON.stringify works fine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, chai, should.js

A function returns an array of objects. When I compare the actual result with an expected result using `JSON.stringify` the values are identical. However comparison using `should.deep.equal` or `_.isEqual` fails. Had anyone encountered such issue?

Comment: Could you add some sample objects to your question?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `should.js`, but is it possible that they are checking not just values but references also? The underscore issue seems to be the same as [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316043/underscore-isequal-and-json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized what the issue was. It is caused by the fact that `JSON.stringify` misses fields with `undefined` values. E.g. result of applying `JSON.stringify` to the following object `{field: 'value', undefinedField: undefined}` is `{"field": "value"}`. Hence

```
JSON.stringify({field: 'value', undefinedField: undefined}) === JSON.stringify({field: 'value'})`
```

But

```
{field: 'value', undefinedField: undefined}.should.deep.equal({field: 'value'})
```

fails